# Reload two diffrent div in one action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am building a webshop and when you put a product into the shopping cart, i want to update two different div. 
One of the div will be updated without any problems.

```
<script>
function submitForm(id) {
$.ajax({type:'POST', url: '/_script/add_ajax.php', data:$('#add'+id).serialize(), success: function(response) {
    $('#add'+id).find('.kassaajax'+id).html(response);
}});

return false;
}
</script>
<form id="add<?php echo $prodID; ?>" onsubmit="return submitForm(<?php echo $prodID; ?>);">
<div class="kassaajax<?php echo $prodID; ?>"></div>
```

But i also want that #kassaajax been reloaded.

```
<div id="kassaajax"><?php include('inc/kassa.php'); ?></div>
```

Comment: return the content in ajax and put it in div? You cant just reload that php into div, it is included at the page load

Comment: What kind of data should be in the div's? Maybe you can have add_ajax.php return a JSON object and take parts of that object to update the HTML?

Comment: maybe you want to use a MVC solution here and go with angular , knockout or another framework

Answer (score 0):

As that div has an ID, so just put the response in it like:

```
function submitForm(id) {
    $.ajax({
       type:'POST', 
       url: '/_script/add_ajax.php', 
       data:$('#add'+id).serialize(), 
       success: function(response) {
           $('#add'+id).find('.kassaajax'+id).html(response);
           $('#kassaajax').html(response); // <----add this to update
       }
    });
    return false;
}
```